# Create an edit user profile page in MeteorJS

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have recently switched over to MeteorJS and am loving it so far!

I do have a quick question. I have used the meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 plugin for my login services and find it great. I did include the extra functionality to "edit profile" as mentioned in the documentation here:

https://github.com/ianmartorell/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3

My question is do I need to create a separate edit profile page for this to happen, or is there a way to include the edit profile link within the {{> loginButtons}} template itself? Meaning do I need to create a form somewhere to update the database with the user's updated details?

I've gotten the button to work, but as of now it doesn't do anything. Ideally I'd like it to take them to a new page where their details are editable. Any way to make this happen, or anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you will need to manually create the route that points to the template that enables a user to edit their profile. There is no out of the box way to do it.

Regards,